# Child component updating Parent object without two-way binding?

Tags: angular

Unexpected behavior that I am not using two way binding with a parent component that sends an object to the child. But the child component is able to update the parent component's object without EventEmitter or @Output

Intially, I was using @Output with an Event Emitter. But I striped my code to following

Where in ParentComponent.ts , an object is defined as such
`public parentString : string;`

ParentCompoent.html

```
<childComponent 
  [parentString] = "parentString"
/childComponent>
```

And in ChildComponent.ts

```
@Input() parentString : string;

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(){
}

ngOnInit(){
  this.parentString = "being updated in the child component";
}
  
}
```

I find in this example the child component is updating the parent component object. Shouldn't I need to be using two way binding and @Output for this to be true. I am not interested in rendering in the html this object. I am just interested in the child component to be able to use and change the parent's object. Is that the difference?

I might be missing something elsewhere in the code. This is a reduction of the codebase I am looking at. But I think it's accurate in terms of the structure of the parent and child component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular does not stop you from mutating properties passed from the parent to the child. It's just advisable to be explicit with the mutation by using `@Output` so that you can better track state changes. You can create an unmaintainable mess out of your codebase with every front-end framework, even Angular.